# Wifi not detected in my HP pavilion 15-N011TU running Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, hp

I bought a new HP pavilion laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 on it. It is not detecting any wireless connections. Wired connection works fine.

```
$ sudo lspci -nn | grep Network 

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7630]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no driver for your device. Please see here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146 I suggest you buy a USB wireless until a driver is developed. You may wish to register with Launchpad and add to the bug report I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least you can get the Bluetooth working by following the steps:

First, you will need to upgrade your kernel.

For a 32-bit system:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.0-031100-generic_3.11.0-031100.201309021735_i386.deb   
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.0-031100_3.11.0-031100.201309021735_all.deb    
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11-saucy/linux-image-3.11.0-031100-generic_3.11.0-031100.201309021735_i386.deb
```

For a 64-bit system:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.0-031100-generic_3.11.0-031100.201309021735_amd64.deb    
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11-saucy/linux-headers-3.11.0-031100_3.11.0-031100.201309021735_all.deb    
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11-saucy/linux-image-3.11.0-031100-generic_3.11.0-031100.201309021735_amd64.deb
```

For both 32-bit & 64-bit systems, run the following command to install the kernel images:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.11.0*.deb linux-image-3.11.0*.deb
```

After booting into the new kernel, type:

```
sudo insmod /lib/modules/3.11.4-031104-generic/kernel/drivers/staging/btmtk_usb.ko
```

Now, to load the module on every reboot, add `btmtk_usb` to `/etc/modules` and then type:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```